# How to inherit crm.lead to my custom module in openerp

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I'm trying to inherit crm.lead into my custom module.Following is my code
lead.py

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class res_partner(osv.osv):
 _name = 
 _inherit = 'crm.lead'
 _description = "adding fields to crm.lead"
 _coloumns = {
    'nitesh': fields.char('Nitesh',size=64)
 }
```

Lead-view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<!-- ========================This is Form layout===============================-->
    <record id="crm_case_form_view_leads" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">CRM - Leads Form</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="partner_name" postion="after">
                <field name="nitesh"/>
            </field>
       </field>
    </record>



<!-- ========================= Action Layout ============================= -->

    <record id="create_lead" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Lead Form</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="crm_case_form_view_leads"/>
    </record>


       <!-- ===========================Menu Settings=========================== -->
    <menuitem name="Lead" id="menu_lis_lab"/>
        <menuitem name="Lead Info" id="sublead_menu" parent="menu_lis_lab"/>
            <menuitem name="Create Lead" id="create_lead"  parent="sublead_menu" action="create_lead"/>     
</data>
</openerp>
```

following Error given:

```
'You may need to add a dependency on the parent class\' module.' % (name, parent_name))
TypeError: The model "crm.lead" specifies an unexisting parent class "crm.lead"
```

You may need to add a dependency on the parent class' module.

Can anyone please tell me where did i go wrong.Thanks in advance

Now i added dependency in **openerp**.py

**openerp**.py is

```
{
'name': 'Lead Information',
'version': '0.1',
'category': 'Tools',
'description': """This module is Lead information.""",
'author': 'Nitesh',
'website': '',
'depends': ['base','crm'],
'init_xml': ['customer_view.xml'],
'update_xml': [],
'demo_xml': [],
'installable': True,
'active': True,
'application': True
}
```

and i'm getting this error :

```
except_orm: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inherit from object than please give it a proper name. First check the code of already developed modules, to see how they inherit. And know the meaning of **_inherit** and **_name**.

Make the following change in your .py file.

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class crm_lead(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'
    _description = "adding fields to crm.lead"
    _coloumns = {
        'nitesh': fields.char('Nitesh',size=64)
    }
```

And just in your view.xml you only put this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <!-- ========================This is Form layout===============================-->
    <record id="crm_case_form_view_leads_extended" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">CRM - Leads Form</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="partner_name" postion="after">
                <field name="nitesh"/>
            </field>
       </field>
    </record>

</data>
</openerp>
```

With that you will see the nitesh filed add on crm.lead form.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Odedra i have done ur changes i'm still getting the error as "except_orm: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')
"

Comment: have you make a new module or do change on core module ?

Comment: I'm trying to do in new module.Should i make changes in Core Module

Comment: Nope. Better to make a new module. May i know you want menu as you define or just add char field in crm.lead form. Because your .xml file is wrong like id and all things.

Comment: Actually i have done similar thing for Customer form and i completed it successfully.Now i want to modify Lead form. In existing lead i want to hide some fields and add some more field. Can i edit both customer form and lead form by inheriting them to a one new custom module or should i need to create two different things??

Comment: You can not inherit multiple form in one form view. You need to inherit differently. First try above code and see in crm.lead form that filed you see that. If you want to hide filed that not a big deal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46658/discussion-between-odedra-and-nitesh)